# Mount public NAS: mount.cifs: permission denied

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

quick question:

Trying to auto-mount my Nas. I only use the public share (so don't need passwords) and I have followed this instruction:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

So this is the line I added to the fstab:

```
 //nas/public /media/public cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

I do automount, but I don't have permission to access it. If I go in my network and manually mount(and log in with anonymous) it does work, and I have full access. So only the auto-mount doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You didn't add your fstab line in your question...

Comment: always best to [edit] your post with additional information rather than just add to the comment chain. I've edited your question for youo.